# Laravel routing triggers 500 error on subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I am trying to put my laravel project on a live server. It is supposed to run on subdomain http://api.domain.com. The problem is it shows 500 internal error on any route except:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Folder structure:

/

--laravel

--subdoms

----api

--www

When I put content of public folder of laravel project into www folder it runs on domain.com perfectly, database, authenticating, routing, it works.

When I put that content into api folder and I visit api.domain.com it loads welcome view. But when I add another route:

```
Route::get('testing', function() {
    return "Tested.";
});
```

This shows 500 internal error.

Thank you for any feedback.

Edit: my .htaccess file in public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Here is some information that would be useful:
What are you using to serve your pages (apache, nginx, or just prototyping with the php artisan serve command)?  
What OS are you using?

Comment: offline I use php artisan serve command, Windows and on that server: Linux CentOS, Apache 2.2.

Comment: do you have the subdomain settings linked in  in  /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/ ?

Comment: I don't even have this folder.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?